# Report with sub-report not generating in Reporting Services 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, subreport

This is my first attempt at employing sub reports and my overall experience with reporting services is minimal (edits to existing reports, creation of some basic reports).

I have added a sub report to a an existing report. The sub report returns in about 1 second when tested separately. The query that powers it returns in less than a second in Management Studio.

The main report takes about 2 minutes to run without the sub report component. With the sub report however, it does not appear to return at all after more than 10 minutes.

Is there something fundamental I am missing here?

This is running on SQL Server 2005 and the project is in Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are doing with the subreports. Each subreport is like a complete report request so you have to be careful if you are putting them in a repeating element like a table or list. If you do the performance of your report will quickly deteriorate with the size of your table/list.